# Cant pass array to post in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, http, post, curl

This is my array:

```
Array
(
    [lead_id] => 107
    [source_type] => 1
    [source_id] => 1
    [lead_content] => {"1":"11","2":"11"}
    [user_ip] => ::1
    [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.36
    [user_referer] => 
    [old_user_lead_id] => 5
    [user_id] => 1
    [lead_status_id] => 1
    [lead_management_comment] => 
    [time] => 2016-02-17 20:11:24
    [utm_source] => 
    [utm_medium] => 
    [utm_term] => 
    [utm_content] => 
    [utm_campaign] => 
    [lead_status_name] => Received
)
```

I try to send him with this code:

```
 $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    if ($post) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, get_site_url());
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

In the other side i have code that just print the $_POST. But this code is not print anything with this array (with other array it's work fine).
Why the array does not pass? Could it be because of there is any illegal characters in my array?

Thanks :)

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary but try `$post = array_map('urlencode', $post);`

Comment: Warning: urlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in

Comment: Then you're array is multi-dimensional and not as shown in the question.

Comment: You're right, I arranged it so that it will be a one-dimensional now. But still, the problem is not resolved :/

Comment: Can you `var_dump` the array (instead of `print_r`)? I have tested simulating **your array** and it work (also w/out http_build_query... ).

Comment: Sure: http://pastebin.com/eFhzZQyp
Where did you try this?

Comment: In your example there is not multi-dimensional array

Comment: Yes, I fixed the problem with the two-dimensional array. it was just a copy & paste problem. But unfortunately it did not solved the problem :/

Comment: Maybe a problem in your `$url` file, not in the original array. Have you checked server error?

Answer (score 0):

problem solved. It was not the array. 
The problem was in the file that receives the data.
He had a protection against displaying too many characters. It was very stupid of me.

Thanks for the help everyone :)

Answer (score -2):

<del>You can't pass directly an array to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, you have to</del>

To correctly send **multi-dimensional array,** you have to use `http_build_query()` before:

```
(...)
if ($post) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query( $post ));
}
(...)
```

#### Edit:

My first answer totally not-correct, but I leave it modified because it is **correct** for multidimensional arrays.

Comment: thanks you for the answer. but its still not working for me.

Comment: _"You can't pass directly an array to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS"_ Contrary to all of the documentation.

Comment: @AbraCadaver yes you are totally right. My mistake, I remembered evil. I'll delete answer.