# php echoing multi-dimensional array in JSON form

Tags: java, php, arrays, json, list

I am trying to display all the users in my database in `JSON` form in an `array`. This is what I have - but it is not in the form that I want it in

```
{
  "username": [
    "bobgreen",
    "jacksmitd",
    "samson",
  ]
  "forename": [
    "Bob",
    "Jack",
    "Sam",
  ],
  "surname": [
    "O'Conor",
    "Smitd",
    "Son",
  ]
}
```

This is my code that gives this output...

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($outcome)){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($outcome)){
        $finalOutcome["username"][] = $row["username"];
        $finalOutcome["forename"][] = $row["forename"];
        $finalOutcome["surname"][] = $row["surname"];
    }
    echo json_encode($finalOutcome); 
}
```

I want to store all of the relevant details within  braces so like:

```
{
    "username":"bobgreen"
    "forename":"Bob"
    "surname":"O'Conor"
}
{
    "username":"jacksmitd"
    "forename":"Jack"
    "surname":"Smitd"
}
{
    "username":"samson"
    "forename":"Sam"
    "surname":"Son"
}
```

Also how do I extract all the relevant data from each brace and store in a list in Java? Because I am trying to store all the details on a per users basis and I wasn't sure how to do it with my first `JSON` array

Comment: Sorry, Java. I want to use the `username`, `forename` and `surname` for every user as I want to add it to a list.

Answer (score 1):

**Regarding main question:**

You have to use this syntax:

```
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $outcome ) )
{
    $finalOutcome[] = array
    (
        "username" => $row["username"],
        "forename" => $row["forename"],
        "surname"  => $row["surname"]
    );
}
echo json_encode( $finalOutcome );
```

Substantially, in your original query you increment `$finalOutcome` sub-arrays instead of `$finalOutcome`

Comment: My answer is almost the same. The output will be the same with a different solution that also works.

Comment: It doesn't work! I'm getting `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')' ` in `PostMan`

Comment: @AndreCardoso No. If the id start from 1, i.e., you will obtain `{"1":{"username":"johnd","forename":"john","surname":"doe"}}` instead of `[{"username":"johnd","forename":"john","surname":"doe"}]`

Comment: @SamuelGeorgeszusz yes, you are right, typo error inside definition! replace `;` with `,`

Comment: Thank you. It works. Now the question is how do I extract out the information for each username? I want to do add them to a list in Java

Comment: @SamuelGeorgeszusz I am not a java expert.

Comment: @fusion3k, try the code I posted. As you will see, works perfectly, try before say that isn't work!

Comment: @fusion3k all is need is an array of user info, and in your solution it is possible as in mine solution too. The loop will be exactly the same.

Comment: @AndreCardoso yes, an array, not an object

Comment: @fusion3k understand WHAT I posted, then try it yourself! https://3v4l.org/ctAnI. Click "eval();" to see the output and tell me that this is not what the answer author need.

Comment: I understand, man. see [json syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp): in your example the json is an **object**, not an array. it's very simple: an array (in square brackets),
an object (in curly braces). In our example where are square brackets?

Comment: yep, agree. I was focusing on output instead the process, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You can to do a better solution (comparated to the question code):

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($outcome)){
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($outcome)){

    $userId = $row["id"];
    $finalOutcome[$userId]["username"] = $row["username"];
    $finalOutcome[$userId]["forename"] = $row["forename"];
    $finalOutcome[$userId]["surname"] = $row["surname"];
}
echo json_encode($finalOutcome);
```

And the output will be:

```
[
    {
        "username":"username0",
        "forename":"forename0",
        "surname":"surname0"
    }, 
    {
        "username":"username1",
        "forename":"forename1",
        "surname":"surname1"
    }
]
```

Comment: No, if `$row["id"]` doesn't start from 0 and/or have a gap

Comment: Ok, but what is the problem if doesn't start with `0`? The output will be exactly the same! This solution is only to group the info by user, their ids isn't used as you can see.

Comment: if the id doesn't start from 0, json convert it in object instead of array. json doesn't allow associative arrays

Comment: Don't be angry, Andre. Everyone makes mistakes (see [this my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35464664/3294262), i.e.). 
It is not a race, and I don't think that my answer is better than yours. On the contrary, your answer could be better than mine, because it returns also the id. I have only remarked than with your answer OP obtains an object instead of an array. I remarked this because I'm better than you? Not at all, only because I stumbled in this error before you. I'm sure that you have a lot of stuff to teach me and that your contribute in SO is valuable. Peace.